# Carousel disappears using custom HTML on Joomla

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla, module

My Carousel images are disappearing on Joomla. I'm trying to have an automatic banner for a webpage using the below code from W3 Schools, I have entered the code into a custom module in Joomla. I have also tried using it with Notepad++ and opening it in a browser and it works completely fine. However, on the Joomla page the images become white and do not display. I am able to switch between them an the CSS for the slider and arrows seems to work. Please find my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        * {box-sizing: border-box;}
        body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
        .mySlides {display: none;}
        img {vertical-align: middle;}
        /* Slideshow container */
        .slideshow-container {
        max-width: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        }
        /* Caption text */
        .text {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        }
        /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
        .numbertext {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        }
        /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
        .dot {
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        margin: 0 2px;
        background-color: #bbb;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
        }
        .active {
        background-color: #717171;
        }
        /* Fading animation */
        .fade {
        -webkit-animation-name: fade;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
        animation-name: fade;
        animation-duration: 1.5s;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes fade {
        from {opacity: .4} 
        to {opacity: 1}
        }
        @keyframes fade {
        from {opacity: .4} 
        to {opacity: 1}
        }
        /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
        @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        .text {font-size: 11px}
        }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <h2>Automatic Slideshow</h2>
    <p>Change image every 2 seconds:</p>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" 
style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg" 
style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img 
src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" 
style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot"></span> 
        <span class="dot"></span> 
        <span class="dot"></span> 
    </div>
    <script>
        var slideIndex = 0;
        showSlides();

        function showSlides() {
            var i;
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
               slides[i].style.display = "none";  
            }
            slideIndex++;
            if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", 
 "");
            }
            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            setTimeout(showSlides, 6000); // Change image every 6 seconds
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Custom HTML Module - it disables all of your scripts
I advice you to use something else for using JS in module - for example - Flexi Custom Code

Comment: I was already using Flexi Custom code, and it is still creating the same issue.

Comment: Could you show me - what you are inserting in module? And - maybe it's easier to usesome slideshows modules instead of plain code?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown is for an entire html document, you can't simply dump that whole into another entire html document. Joomla is a CMS, you shouldn't just drop html into it. To add an image carousel it would be better to create your own module to do that.